# Bitrix XML_İD Где хранится?

Tags: php, битрикс, cms

Есть свойство со списком, в нем есть XML_ID , как найти этот XML_ID где он хранится ?

Поле c XML_İD самое первое слева

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри [тут](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cuserfieldenum/getlist.php), используй GetList в фильтр добавь ID свойства